# When I change branch some localized keys doesn't get translated unless I recompile the project

Tags: ios, swift, git, caching, localization

I've been dealing with localization on several projects but it is the first time this happens to me.

When I compile my project on a new branch, some keys are not translated although everything is right (key exists, have a value and localize function is properly called).

I first though it was about some local cache but it also happens on my colleagues Mac.

The problem disappears after recompiling the project.

When I print the used Bundle this is what I get :

```
NSBundle </Users/myname/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/0BBE6113-F013-4E0C-A47A-C40C47A5AD58/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/9FE75EF1-EA8C-4DDA-839B-D012EDD3C3E7/My App.app> (loaded)
```

I'm kind of worried about this bug being shipped to the Store when I will archive my next version.

Comment: So what's the difference between your two branches if you expect changes to apply without recompilation? Is it only the localisation file being changed?

Comment: Both branches have the same localization file, the difference between them is totally unrelated to the localization file. What I do is, switch branch, compile -> some keys are not translated. I recompile the same branch without changing anything -> all keys are properly translated.

Comment: So they're only translated on 2nd compilation? You need to be aware of Xcode build system's caching mechanism, which uses DerivedData as a cache - switching branches without deleting DerivedData can very easily cause weird build issues that would never actually occur in a clean environment.